# Describe all non-injective group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ to the multiplictive group of $\mathbb Q[i]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Describe all non-injective group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ to the multiplictive group of $\mathbb Q[i]$.

**Note**: $Q[i]=\{a+bi |a,b \in \mathbb Q\}$, and $0 \notin Q[i]$

**What I've done so far**: Group homomorphisms is determined by assigning the generator of the group with a value. So $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Q[i]$ is determined by the value assigned to $f(1)$.

So if $f(1)=a+bi$ then $f(m)=(a+bi)^m$? I'm not sure if this is good. Notice that for negative $m$ you might not get a result in $\mathbb Q[i]$? And if this does determine all homomorphisms $f: \mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Q[i]$, then how do I determine the non-injective ones?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got quite close. In order to be non-injective, you need $f(n) = f(m)$ for some $n\ne m \in \mathbb N$. This means that you need $(a+bi)^m = (a+bi)^n$ - or after division, $(a+bi)^k = 1$. So $(a+bi)$ must be a $k^{th}$ root of unity. Can you finish from here?

Hint: how many $k^{th}$ roots of unity are there in $\mathbb Q[i]$?

Comment: So it's $f(1)=1,-1,i,-i$?

Answer (score 0):

So far, so good.

Yes, as addition in $\Bbb Z$ goes to multiplication in $\Bbb Q[i]$, we will have
$$f(n)=f(1+1+\dots+1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)\cdots f(1)=f(1)^n\,.$$
Negative exponents don't lead out of $\Bbb Q[i]$ because 
$$\frac1{a+bi}=\frac{a-bi}{a^2+b^2}\,.$$
Further hint: check the *kernel* of $f(n):=z^n$ where $z=f(1)$ characterizes the homomorphism $f$.